# Create a toast based on items inputted

Tags: android, view, toast

I am attempting to create a toast pop-up when the icon at the bottom of the layout (the screen icon) https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8WgN.png

I want the information entered to be put into the toast notification like a shipping address

First Last

Street

City State Zip

is there a way to do this where the toast calls on the Id's for the EditText views?

The .xml with the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:stretchColumns="2" android:orientation="vertical">
 <TableRow>
     <TextView
         android:text="First Name"
         android:padding="3dip" android:layout_column="0"/>
     <TextView
         android:text="Last Name" android:padding="3dip"/>

 </TableRow>
 <TableRow>
   <EditText 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/EditText01" 
            android:inputType="textPersonName"      
            android:width="150dip"/>
  <EditText android:singleLine="true" 
            android:inputType="textPersonName" 
            android:isScrollContainer="false" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/EditText02" 
            android:lines="1" android:width="150dip"></EditText>
  </TableRow>
  <View
     android:background="#FF909090" android:layout_height="2px"/>
  <TableRow>
     <TextView
         android:text="Street Address"
         android:padding="3dip" android:layout_column="0"/>
  </TableRow>

  <TableLayout>
    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TextView 
              android:text="Line 1"
               android:padding="3dip" 
                            android:layout_column="0"/>
    <EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/EditText03" 
                            android:inputType="textPostalAddress" 
                            android:width="255dip"/>
   </TableRow>
   <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent">
      <TextView 
    android:text="Line 2"
    android:padding="3dip" android:layout_column="0"/>
   <EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/EditText04" 
                            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"/>
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TableLayout>
<TableRow>
<TextView
 android:text="City"
 android:padding="3dip" 
 android:layout_column="0" />
<EditText 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/EditText05" 
 android:inputType="text" 
 android:layout_width="120px"/>
</TableRow>
<TableLayout>
  <TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:text="@string/state" />
    <Spinner 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/state"
        android:id="@+id/Spinner01" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Zipcode" />
    <EditText 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:inputType="phone" android:width="80px"/>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</TableLayout>
<View
     android:background="#FF909090" android:layout_height="2px"/>
 <TableRow>
  <TextView
   android:layout_width="120px"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Telephone Number" 
   android:padding="3dip"/>
 </TableRow>
 <TableLayout>
  <TableRow>
   <EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:layout_width="120dip" />
  <Button android:id="@+id/Button01"   
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:padding="3dip" 
          android:background="@drawable/ic_monitor_grey"         
          android:clickable="true" />
  </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
  </TableLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

With my .java file being

```
public class Basic extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.basic);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.state_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to do a few things.

1. For each editText area you want to get the values from, you'll want to define an android:id using the following style of syntax
2. Retrieve the views you'd like to use from your xml layout inside the Java.  Based on the above, you'd want to add something to you onCreate like:

   EditText phoneField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_field)
3. Retrieve the value from the EditText object

   String phoneNumber = phoneField.getText().toString()
4. Show the field in a Toast message
   Toast toDisplay = Toast.makeText(context, phoneNumber)
   toDisplay.show()

There are obviously tons of additional things you could do, but that would be about the minimum.

Comment: I attempted this, but the String phoneNumber = phoneField.getText() says it has to be Editable phoneNumber = phoneField.getText()..is that a problem?

Comment: That is not a problem.  To get the string value, call .toString on the Editable that is returned.  I've edited my answer to show the correct call.